# sqlalchemy model init morphing model properties to nonetype

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a user model that I am trying to initialize and I keep getting

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'

Upon further inspection I have learned that sqlalchemy converts its models to mappers which contain attributes InstrumentedAttribute making them queryable.Apparently this all happens at the time of initialization of the object.

This only happens with the usermodel and nothing else.

I have tried to use app_context to see if it is due to the db not being in scope. But it hasn't helped.

```
class userData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    # TODO need to add hashing for the password
    password = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)

    facility_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('facility.id'), nullable=True)
    auth_hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(userData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item is 'facility':
            facility = facilityData.query.filter(facilityData.id == self.facility_id).first()
            if facility is None:
               return "No Facility Found"
            else:
                return facility.facility_name
```

For reference, this one worked just fine:

```
class barcodeData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'barcodes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    medid = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

    user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, data):
        '''class constructor'''
        self.barcode = data.get('barcode')
        self.medid = data.get('medid')
        self.user = data.get('user')
```

This is the error I get when I try to create a new userData object.

```
import models
import app
with app.app.app_context():
    models.userData(name='admin2', password='test2',  facility_id=1)
```

I have even tried the other way around without app_context(), and then specifically importing userData from models. Also tried to use app_context interchangeably with each iteration.

```
attributes.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    258
    259     def __set__(self, instance, value):
--> 260         self.impl.set(
    261             instance_state(instance), instance_dict(instance),      value,        None
    262         )

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Comment: Trying to override `__getattr__` of an SQLAlchemy class is a bad idea if you don't know its inner workings well, and even then it's not the best idea. It does _a lot_ of... alchemy to the model classes. Just saying.

Comment: yeah, i did some digging around to find out what happens under the hood when a class of a model object is instantiated. IDK why I was still using the ```__getattr__``` method in python3 where there are property decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just realized why this behavior is happening. Basically, it has nothing to do with db scope or anything of that sort.

The issue is because the during the time the class gets instantiated, the attributes of the class get turned into a queryable attributes, this means that sqlalchemy needs to reference said attributes. Which it is doing by using the `__getattr__` in order infer type(db.Column) before creating the object.

Since, I overrode the `__getattr__` in hopes of making serialization to json easier for my output, it is using the value returned by default which is **None**. This is what is causing the error.

```
@property
def facility(self)->str:
    # do stuff to get facility_name
    return facility_name
```